# Python 2.7 fitting returns wrong values from multiple methods

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, data-fitting

I am using Python 2.7. to general data analysis of various sorts however I am facing a problem with fitting my data.

If I try to fit my data using Binned LH, UnBinned LH, Chi2, Kmeans etc - the software will always return the same value (exact!), even if i supply different starting parameters to the the fit. For some method, the returned value is completely off - see attached KMeans plot.

Following packages are showing problems

Probfit
Iminuit
Sklearn
Scipy

Any ideas what is going on?

My own
[image: My own fitting]

Same code on a coworkers computer (same setup)
[image: My coworkers computer]

Comment: If you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem, it is far more probable to get an answer. Please try to create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ...one thing to consider as well...if you compare to a second machine...are you sure that the according packages are the same version?

Comment: Everything is fully updated on both machines